# How to instantiate DataContext object in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext

I want to be able to create an instance of the `DataContext` object for my WPF StartupUri window in XAML, as opposed to creating it code and then setting the `DataContext` property programmaticly.

The main reason is I don't need to access the object created externally and I don't want to have to write code behind just for setting the `DataContext`.

I'm sure I've read somewhere how to instantiate the `DataContext` object in XAML but I can't find it in any of the usual places...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You add an XML namespace for whatever namespace your DataContext lives in, create an instance of it in the Window Resources and set the DataContext to that resource:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyViewModel x:Key="MyViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewModel}">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Does this work in .NET framework 4.5? I tried this code and it says ... `The type 'local:MyViewModel' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly and that all referenced assemblies have been built.`

Comment: @RafafTahsin did you ensure you had the namespace correctly? Also, if you added the referenced type to the project but have not yet built, the WPF designer gets a little confused. Have you tried building?

Comment: If You are also using a `ResourceDictionary`, `local:MyViewModel` goes inside the dictionary (but any `MergedDictionary`)

Answer (score 28):

You can just specify this directly in XAML for the entire Window:

```
<Window 
    ... xmlns definitions ...
>
   <Window.DataContext>
        <local:CustomViewModel />
   </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

This creates a view model named "CustomViewModel" in the namespace aliased to local, directly as the DataContext for the Window.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming this code:

```
public abstract class BaseView { }
public class RuntimeView : BaseView { }
public class DesigntimeView : BaseView { }
```

Try this:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:RuntimeView />
</Page.DataContext>
<d:Page.DataContext>
    <local:DesigntimeView />
</d:Page.DataContext>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Best of luck!

Comment: +1 because this shows both run and designtime, and doesn't make use of x:Key but instead places the DataContext directly in the element where it belongs

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set the DataContext as same control class:

```
    <Window x:Class="TabControl.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControl"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"        
            >
</Window>
```

**use RelativeSource binding.**

or just

```
     <Window x:Class="TabControl.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControl"
                Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"                        
                >
<Window.DataContext>
< new instance of any viewModel here....>
</Window.DataContext>
    </Window>
```

**If want to assign an instance of different class than itself.**