# Wpf Databinding... how?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

How can I set the binding in Xaml

**Xaml Code:**

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=compassLogCollection}"
```

**.cs Code**

```
 compassDataGrid.DataContext = LogSession.compassLogCollection;
```

compassLogCollection is a **static** `ObservableCollection<>`

and

`LogSession` is a singleton (if it matters)

Comment: I don't have VS available to test but can you just set `ItemSource = {Binding}`?

Comment: thats correct and works Fine, but i need to set the path

Comment: That makes no sense - either it solves your issue or it doesn't.

Comment: is there a way to do it all in Xaml?

Comment: I posted Xaml. Do you mean you want to set your `DataContext` in Xaml too?

Comment: I wrote a blog article a few months back specifically for new WPF users who don't quite understand the `DataContext`. You may be interested in checking it out, as it will help you understand how WPF's binding system works :) [What is this “DataContext” you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, you can just change your `Xaml` as follows:

```
 ItemSource = {Binding}
```

This tells the `ItemSource` to bind directly to the `DataContext`.

Your follow-up question asks how to assign the `DataContext` in Xaml. For this I suggest you take a look at this question - [How to instantiate DataContext object in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521699/how-to-instantiate-datacontext-object-in-xaml). If that doesn't work then you should ask another question.