# How to locate the source of Binded property

Tags: .net, xaml, mvvm

this might be a very basic question , I am new to silverlight and MVVM ,

i have a button

```
  <Button  IsEnabled="{Binding IsUpdatingStatus}"> </Button>
```

Just wanted to know if i have to find the source of IsUpdatingStatus (in which view model it exists)
Where can i See the Direction starting From Xaml

**EDIT :**

My xaml has markup like this :

```
  <UserControl x:Class="LMS.Client.View.LeadStatusControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
        xmlns:vc="clr-namespace:LMS.Client.Controls"
        xmlns:control="clr-namespace:LMS.Client.Controls;assembly=LMS.Client.Common"
        xmlns:commanding="clr-namespace:LMS.Client.Commanding;assembly=LMS.Client.Common"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource Content.ContentControlStyle}">

    .....
```

If I am missing something , Please let me know , tell me if i am something wrong

```
this is actually complete Xaml

:



<UserControl x:Class="LMS.Client.View.LeadStatusControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
    xmlns:vc="clr-namespace:LMS.Client.Controls"
    xmlns:control="clr-namespace:LMS.Client.Controls;assembly=LMS.Client.Common"
    xmlns:commanding="clr-namespace:LMS.Client.Commanding;assembly=LMS.Client.Common"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource Content.ContentControlStyle}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Silver" CornerRadius="8" Margin="10,0,10,20" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="Silver" Margin="0,30,0,30"/>

                    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}" Text="Update Status" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Lead Status" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}"/>
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding UpdatingStatus}" Style="{StaticResource SemiComboBoxStyle}"
                                  Margin="5,0,5,0" DisplayMemberPath="StatusCode" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUpdatingStatus,Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStatusEditable}"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Reason" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}"/>
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding LeadStatusReasons}" Style="{StaticResource SemiComboBoxStyle}"
                                  Margin="5,0,5,0" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStatusReason,Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStatusEditable}"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="Comments" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStatusEditable}" Text="{Binding Entity.DisqualificationComments,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5,0,5,0" Height="100" Style="{StaticResource SemiTextBoxStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Text="CS Number" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStatusEditable}" Text="{Binding Entity.CSNumber,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Margin="5,0,5,0" Style="{StaticResource SemiTextBoxStyle}"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Text="Contract No" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStatusEditable}" Text="{Binding Entity.ContractNo,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5,0,5,0" Style="{StaticResource SemiTextBoxStyle}"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" Text="Site No" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStatusEditable}" Text="{Binding Entity.SiteNo,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5,0,5,0" Style="{StaticResource SemiTextBoxStyle}"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Text="Schedule Date" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}"/>
                        <control:CustomizedDatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Margin="5,0,5,0" Style="{StaticResource SemiDatePickerStyle}" Width="200" 
                                    SelectedDate="{Binding Entity.ScheduleDate,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStatusEditable}"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" Text="Reschedule Date" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}"/>
                        <control:CustomizedDatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Margin="5,0,5,0" Style="{StaticResource SemiDatePickerStyle}" Width="200" 
                                    SelectedDate="{Binding Entity.RescheduledDate,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStatusEditable}"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="9" Text="Followup Date" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}"/>
                        <control:CustomizedDatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" Margin="5,0,5,0" Style="{StaticResource SemiDatePickerStyle}" Width="200" 
                                    SelectedDate="{Binding Entity.FollowupDate,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStatusEditable}"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="10" Text="Installed Date" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}"/>
                        <control:CustomizedDatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10" Margin="5,0,5,0" Style="{StaticResource SemiDatePickerStyle}" Width="200" 
                                    SelectedDate="{Binding Entity.InstalledDate,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStatusEditable}"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="11" Text="Online Date" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}"/>
                        <control:CustomizedDatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="11" Margin="5,0,5,0" Style="{StaticResource SemiDatePickerStyle}" Width="200" 
                                    SelectedDate="{Binding Entity.OnlineDate,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStatusEditable}"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="12" Text="Purchasing Submitted Date" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}"/>
                        <control:CustomizedDatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="12" Margin="5,0,5,0" Style="{StaticResource SemiDatePickerStyle}" Width="200" 
                                    SelectedDate="{Binding Entity.PurchasingSubmittedDate,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStatusEditable}"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="13" Text="Purchased Date" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}"/>
                        <control:CustomizedDatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="13" Margin="5,0,5,0" Style="{StaticResource SemiDatePickerStyle}" Width="200"
                                    SelectedDate="{Binding Entity.PurchasedDate,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStatusEditable}"/>

                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}" Text="Disqualifications" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                        <ListBox Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{Binding SemiListBoxStyle}" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding DisqualificationReasons}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStatusEditable}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}">
                                        <CheckBox.Content>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Reason.DisplayText}" Style="{StaticResource Content.LabelTextStyle}" />
                                        </CheckBox.Content>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,20,10,20" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Width="80"
                                    Command="{Binding SubmitUpdateStatusCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsUpdatingStatus}">
                        <TextBlock Text="Update" Style="{StaticResource Button.TextStyle}"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Width="80" Margin="12,0,0,0"
                                    Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanCancel}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource Common.Cancel}" Style="{StaticResource Button.TextStyle}"/>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ContentControl>
```

Now can you please tell me where could be the location of markup

Comment: at runtime you can check this with Snoop, but at design time i dont know if there are tools or extensions which can help you out

Answer (score 0):

The DataContext property of Button will give you the source of the bound property.

Answer (score 0):

For databinding to work, you need to set the DataContext to a ViewModel. You can do this in various ways. For example in the constructor of a page:

Page.xaml.cs

```
public Page()
{
    DataContext = new PageViewModel();
}
```

When you have a boolean property named IsUpdatingStatus in your PageViewModel, the button will then update its status according to what IsUpdatingStatus is set to.

Some people dislike using the constructor to set the DataContext. You can also set it statically in the XAML file itself, also see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521699/how-to-instantiate-datacontext-object-in-xaml), or use the OnNavigatedTo eventhandler:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) { }
```

I hope this (partly) answers your question.